# How to print a PDF file from TWebBrowser with a background process?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a HTML document in a `TWebBrowser`. I need to transform this document to a PDF file and send it as attachment in a mail. The way that I found is to print the `TWebBrowser` content with a PDF printer. Is there a way to do it without showing a dialog and always use the PDF printer (background process)? Taking into account that the functionality is used by 3 computers and not all of them have the same printer set by default.

I am currently using this code but I have problems since the computers do not have the same index for the printers

```
procedure TfmNavegador.btnImprimirClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  OLECMDID_PRINT               = $00000006;
  OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER     = $00000001;
var
vIn, vOut: OleVariant;
begin
  wbNotificacion.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut) ;
end;
```

Comment: If you don't want to show the print dialog then you should use `OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSE` as second parameter instead of `OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER` that you are curently using. You can read more about printing using TWebBrowser in [this](http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2007/01/print-html-file-using-twebbrowser.html) article. But I'm not sure if it is possible to chose specific printer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

that's all fine?

You can leave each computer already configured as the default printer, or enter the printer's index or select it only once and then leave it automatic, like this code below:

```
// Unit
Uses Vcl.Printers;



procedure TfmNavegador.btnImprimirClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  OLECMDID_PRINT               = $00000006;
  OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER     = $00000001;
var
vIn, vOut: OleVariant;
begin
  // call default printer
  Printer.Printers[ Printer.PrinterIndex ]);

  wbNotificacion.ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vIn, vOut) ;
end;
```